The archive did not include a SYM for the Razorpay.framework with UUIDs. Ensure that archive's SYM folder includes DWARF file for Razorpay.framework

I have tried this:
My podfile code:
bitcode_strip_path = `xcrun --find bitcode_strip`.chop!

  def strip_bitcode_from_framework(bitcode_strip_path, framework_relative_path)
    framework_path = File.join(Dir.pwd, framework_relative_path)
    command = "#{bitcode_strip_path} #{framework_path} -r -o #{framework_path}"
    puts "Stripping bitcode: #{command}"
    system(command)
  end
  
  framework_paths = [ "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/macosx/hermes.framework/hermes",
    "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/macosx/hermes.framework/Versions/Current/hermes",
    "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64/hermes.framework/hermes",
    "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-maccatalyst/hermes.framework/hermes",
    "Pods/razorpay-pod/Pod/Razorpay.xcframework/ios-arm64/Razorpay.framework/Razorpay",  # Add Razorpay path here]
  
  framework_paths.each do |framework_relative_path|
    strip_bitcode_from_framework(bitcode_strip_path, framework_relative_path)
  end


i am facing the same problem after upgrading to Xcode 16.0. I am using "react-native": "0.72.4"

I'm also facing the same issue. Any help would be great.
